# ScalatestRouteTest tests time out when run together but run fine individually

Tags: scala, testing, akka-http

I have a spec for my akka-http route with two tests in it. I can run each of these individually just fine -- but when I run the whole spec (including both tests), the 2nd one fails with

> Request was neither completed nor rejected within 30 seconds

Does anyone know why this is?

I don't know if it's relevant, but each test seems to be logging events twice whether I run them alone or together. (Sometimes the duplicated events are in different dispatchers and sometimes they are in the same one.) I am hitting breakpoints on the log messages twice so I assume the events are really being called twice. Again, not sure if it's relevant, but maybe a clue.

I'm also mocking out dependencies, but I don't think that's the issue.

Dumbed down version of my test:

```
package com.mystuff

import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import com.mystuff._
import org.mockito.Mockito._
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.StatusCodes.{NotFound, OK}
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives
import akka.http.scaladsl.testkit.{RouteTestTimeout, ScalatestRouteTest}
import org.scalatest.{BeforeAndAfterEach, FunSpec, Matchers}

import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.duration._

/**
  * Created by bathalh on 6/2/17.
  */
class OAuthClentServiceASpec extends FunSpec with Matchers with BeforeAndAfterEach with Directives with ScalatestRouteTest
{
    implicit def default(implicit system: ActorSystem) = RouteTestTimeout( 30 seconds )

    private var mockDependencyFun: DependencyFun = _
    private var testObject: MyService = _

    override def beforeEach =
    {
        mockDependencyFun = mock(classOf[DependencyFun])
        when( mockDependencyFun( anyString() ) ).thenReturn( Future successful "OK" )

        testObject = new MyService() {
            def getDepFunction = mockDependencyFun
        }

    }

    describe( "OAuthClentService Application" )
    {
        import akka.http.scaladsl.marshallers.sprayjson.SprayJsonSupport._
        import com.mystuff.MyJsonProtocol._

        describe( "Get a specific client" )
        {
            it( "Returns 404 with useful message when client does not exist" )
            {
                val clientId = "does not exist client"
                Get( s"/clients/$clientId" ) ~> testObject.routes ~> check {
                    status should be (NotFound)
                    responseAs[ErrorResponse] should be (ErrorResponse(Set(s"Client not found: $clientId")))
                }
            }

            it( "Returns client information when client exists" )
            {
                val clientId = "ValidClient"
                Get( s"/clients/$clientId" ) ~> testObject.routes ~> check {
                    status should be (OK)
                    val clientInfo = responseAs[ClientResponse]
                    clientInfo.id should be (clientId)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: RouteTestTimeout definition was useful.

Answer (score 0):

There May be an issue with your connection pool due to which the connection is getting timeout issues.

Try passing timeout explicitly and see if it works out 
`implicit def default(implicit system: ActorSystem) = RouteTestTimeout(50.second)`

Comment: I'm setting it to 30 seconds, which should be enough. But you might be right about the connection pool; I'll mess with my `application.conf` settings and see if I can figure out what's happening. Thanks!